# EWS exchange sometimes not firing NewMail event using StreamingSubscription

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I have application that notifies about new mail, created using EWS managed api (v2.2). I am using StreamingSubscription for listening mailbox events. I've noticed that sometimes NewMail event not fired (I see unhandled mail in mailbox later), no connection/subscription exception being raised, and after some period of time new mail receiving as nothing happened... what could cause such behavior? There's nothing suspicious in exchange logs, event just not being fired... Any Ideas and suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Source:

```
public class ExchangeClient : IDisposable
{
    private ExchangeService _exchange;
    private SubscriptionBase _subscription;
    private StreamingSubscriptionConnection _connection;

    private bool _disposed;
    private bool _disposing;

    public event EventHandler<ExchangeEventArgs> ExchangeEvent;

    public ExchangeClient(string userName, string password, string domain, ExchangeVersion version)
    {
        _exchange = new ExchangeService(version);
        _exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password);

        _exchange.AutodiscoverUrl(userName + "@" + domain);

        var ids = new FolderId[2] { new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root), new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox) };
        var events = new List<EventType>();
        events.Add(EventType.NewMail);

        _subscription = _exchange.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(ids, events.ToArray());
        _connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(_exchange, 30);
        _connection.AddSubscription((StreamingSubscription)_subscription);
        _connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;
        _connection.OnSubscriptionError += OnSubscriptionError;
        _connection.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
        _connection.Open();
    }

    private void OnDisconnect(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        if (!_disposing && _connection != null)
        {
            _connection.Open();
        }
    }

    private void OnSubscriptionError(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        throw args.Exception;
    }

    private void OnNotificationEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_subscription != null)
        {
            if (args.Subscription.Id == _subscription.Id)
            {
                foreach (var notificationEvent in args.Events)
                {
                    switch (notificationEvent.EventType)
                    {
                        case EventType.Status:
                            break;

                        case EventType.NewMail:
                            NotificationReceived(new ExchangeEventArgs(
                            notificationEvent.EventType,
                            ((ItemEvent)notificationEvent).ItemId, ((ItemEvent)notificationEvent).ParentFolderId));
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (_connection.IsOpen)
            _connection.Close();
    }

    private void NotificationReceived(ExchangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ExchangeEvent != null)
        {
            ExchangeEvent(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposing = true;
        Dispose(_disposing);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !_disposed)
        {
            if (_connection != null)
            {
                if (_connection.IsOpen)
                    _connection.Close();
                _connection = null;
            }
            _exchange = null;
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I can answer this question myself - to guarantee continuous work you need to renew your subscription. But here is the weird part: there is no exception being thrown (there is an exception object in `SubscriptionErrorEventArgs` in the `OnDisconnect` event handler:

> Unable to retrieve events for this subscription.  The subscription must be recreated.

Just timeout when you will not get notified about subscription events and after some time you'll continue receiving event notification with an old subscription...

**Update**
The solution I ended up with: if `SubscriptionErrorEventArgs` in the `OnDisconnect` event does not contain an exception - simply open the closed connection, otherwise - raise the `Disconnected` event, and let the parent class decide - should we try `Reconnect` or not (by calling `Reconnect`).

```
public class ExchangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public EventType Type { get; private set; }
    public ItemId ItemId { get; private set; }
    public FolderId FolderId { get; private set; }

    public ExchangeEventArgs(EventType type, ItemId itemId, FolderId folderId)
    {
        Type = type;
        ItemId = itemId;
        FolderId = folderId;
    }
}

public class ExchangeClient : IDisposable
{
    private ExchangeService _exchange;
    private SubscriptionBase _subscription;
    private StreamingSubscriptionConnection _connection;

    private bool _disposed;
    private bool _disposing;

    public event EventHandler<ExchangeEventArgs> ExchangeEvent;
    public event EventHandler<DisconnectEventArgs> Disconnected;

    public ExchangeClient(string userName, string password, string domain, ExchangeVersion version)
    {
        _exchange = new ExchangeService(version);
        _exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials(userName, password);
        _exchange.AutodiscoverUrl(userName + "@" + domain);
        _connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(_exchange, 30);

        CreateSubscription();

        _connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;
        _connection.OnSubscriptionError += OnSubscriptionError;
        _connection.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
        _connection.Open();
    }

    private void CreateSubscription()
    {
        var ids = new FolderId[2] { new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root), new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox) };
        var events = new List<EventType>();
        events.Add(EventType.NewMail);
        if (_subscription != null)
        {
            ((StreamingSubscription)_subscription).Unsubscribe();
            _connection.RemoveSubscription((StreamingSubscription)_subscription);
        }
        _subscription = _exchange.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(ids, events.ToArray());
        _connection.AddSubscription((StreamingSubscription)_subscription);
    }

    private void OnDisconnect(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Exception == null)
        {
            if (!_disposing && _connection != null)
            {
                _connection.Open();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (Disconnected != null)
                Disconnected(this, new DisconnectEventArgs("Exchange exception", args.Exception));
        }
    }

    public bool Reconnect()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_disposing && _connection != null)
            {
                CreateSubscription();

                _connection.Open();

                return true;
            }
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void OnSubscriptionError(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
    {
       OnDisconnect(sender, args);
    }

    private void OnNotificationEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        if (_subscription != null)
        {
            if (args.Subscription.Id == _subscription.Id)
            {
                foreach (var notificationEvent in args.Events)
                {
                    switch (notificationEvent.EventType)
                    {
                        case EventType.Status:
                            break;

                        case EventType.NewMail:
                            NotificationReceived(new ExchangeEventArgs(
                            notificationEvent.EventType,
                            ((ItemEvent)notificationEvent).ItemId, ((ItemEvent)notificationEvent).ParentFolderId));
                            break;

                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }      

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        if (_connection.IsOpen)
            _connection.Close();
    }

    private void NotificationReceived(ExchangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ExchangeEvent != null)
        {
            ExchangeEvent(this, e);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposing = true;
        Dispose(_disposing);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && !_disposed)
        {
            if (_connection != null)
            {
                if (_connection.IsOpen)
                    _connection.Close();
                _connection = null;
            }
            _exchange = null;
            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So how are you renewing the subscription?  Inside the OnDisconnect handler, or using a separate timer?  Would you mind posting the changes you made to the code to get it to work?

Comment: I´m also interested in seeing how you are renewing the subscription. Mind posting the code?

Comment: @MikeRibeiro I've posted this code a while ago - as described in update to original answer:
**The solution I ended up with: if SubscriptionErrorEventArgss inside OnDisconnect event does not contains exception - simply open closed connection, otherwise - raise DIsconnected event, and let parent class decide - should we try Reconnect or not (by calling Reconnect).**

Comment: How to schedule this app to monitor ?